# How to configure nginx with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I have a simple app of 3 containers which all run in the same AWS EC2 server. I want to configure Nginx to act as a reverse-proxy however I'm pretty new with Nginx and don't know how to set the conf file correctly.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: myfrontend:image
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
    image: mybackend:image
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"

  db:
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: myDB
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./initialization/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db-volume:/data/db

volumes:
  db-volume:
```

The backend fetches data from the database and sends it to be presented by the frontend.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  
}

http {
 server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name myDomainName.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://frontend:3000/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend:8400/;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }

 }
}
```

How can I set nginx to serve the frontend and backend containers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Nginx configs to solve your issue

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  
}

http {

 server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  frontend.*;

    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        set $target http://frontend:3000;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $target;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  backend.*;

    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

        set $target http://backend:8400;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $target;
    }
  }
}
```

Nginx will be serving the backend and frontend on different domain names, with the below, etc hosts you will be able to get access to the services on the defined domain names

```
127.0.0.1 backend.me frontend.me
```

Comment: I own a domain name and would like both containers to use it as they work together. Is that not possible with nginx?

Comment: can describe in more detail what do you want to do exactly? if you have two services, you need to have DNS records usually. unless you are planning to host the two applications on the same DNS record with a different location ie (mydomain.com/app1 and mydomain.com/app2)

Comment: It's 1 application that is running a user interface (frontend) and a backend which fetches data from a database. Now that I think about it, i'm not sure if i even need a reverse proxy for this scenario.

Comment: you definitely need a reverse proxy for the frontend, but if the backend and db apps are not supposed to be accessed by the end-users, you should remove the ports section from the docker-compose and  do not include them in nginx configs

Comment: Sadly, this nginx configuration does not work. Returns `502 Bad Gateway` for both domains.